# Force computed variable to update (Firebase VueJS)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I have a navigation link that I want to update when I have signed a user into the app through firebase auth.

I'm managing the user login changes through .onAuthStateChanged in the created hook ()

```
 data () {
    return {
      user: null,
      additionaluserinfo: null,
      isAdmin: false
    }
  },
 created () {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.user = user
        // call for additional user information from firebase
        db.collection('users').where('user_id', '==', user.uid)
          .get()
          .then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              console.log(doc.data())
              this.additionaluserinfo = doc.data()
              this.$store.dispatch('setAdditionalUserInfo', doc.data())
            })
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error getting documents: ', error)
          })

        this.additionaluserinfo = this.$store.state.additionaluserinfo
        if (this.$store.state.additionaluserinfo.role === 'admin' || this.$store.state.additionaluserinfo.role === 'superadmin') {
          this.isAdmin = true
        }
        if (this.$store.state.additionaluserinfo.role === 'superadmin') {
          this.isSuperAdmin = true
        }
      } else {
        this.user = null
        this.additionalUserInfo = null
      }
    })
```

I'm checking to see if the user has user rights on the onAuthSateChanged.

The issue that I have is that I have to refresh the page in order for my navigation bar to update (which displays a div based on v-if="isAdmin" / "isSuperAdmin". Is there a way to force this to update from within onAuthStateChanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either move the block

```
this.additionaluserinfo = this.$store.state.additionaluserinfo
if (this.$store.state.additionaluserinfo.role === 'admin' || this.$store.state.additionaluserinfo.role === 'superadmin') {
  this.isAdmin = true
}
if (this.$store.state.additionaluserinfo.role === 'superadmin') {
  this.isSuperAdmin = true
}
```

inside `this.$store.dispatch('setAdditionalUserInfo', doc.data()).then(() => { /* */ })` or else that code would be evaluated before data are dispatched into the store  (data fetching is async)

Or, better, just remove it and then add:

```
computed: {
    role: () => this.$store.state.additionaluserinfo ? this.$store.state.additionaluserinfo.role : '',
    isAdmin: () => this.role === 'admin' || this.role === 'superadmin', // remove isAdmin from data()
    isSuperAdmin: () => this.role === 'superadmin',
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the first option worked well, the second computed property failed as I couldn't read the value of null

Comment: Hmm problem is lying somewhere else. If additionaluserinfo is null then role's value is `''` and it works as intended.